# TypeScript types for Proxy with dynamic properties

Tags: typescript, proxy, typescript-generics, typescript-types, javascript-proxy

I want to type a JavaScript `Proxy` that allows access to arbitrary properties. A contrived example, an object that maps every property to it's own property name:

```
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, property) {
    return prop;
  }
});
proxy.foo // evaluates to "foo"
// Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

I don't expect TypeScript to automatically infer `proxy.foo` exists, but I would like to provide a type such that it knows it exists *and* the property's value type depends on the property name.

The following mapped type at least prevents TypeScript from complaining about the property not existing, however it infers the type as `string` rather than the more specific `"foo"` property name:

```
const proxy = new Proxy<{ [T in string]: T }>({}, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return prop;
  }
});
proxy.foo // inferred as `string` instead of `"foo"`
```

I have also tried `{ readonly [T in string]: T }`.

Interestingly `({} as { [T in "foo" | "bar"]: T }).foo` will be inferred as `"foo", but I can't enumerate all possible keys.

Is there some way to get TypeScript to use the exact key in the value's type in a mapped type, or some other way of precisely typing a `Proxy` with dynamic properties?

Comment: Would `keyof` be of help?

Comment: This is not possible, as described in the declined suggestion [microsoft/TypeScript#22509](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509).  Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a helper type to create such object with same key and value first

```
// make an object with same key and value
type Fallback<Keys extends string> = { [K in Keys]: K };

type FooBar = Fallback<'foo' | 'bar'>

const foobar = new Proxy<FooBar>({} as FooBar, {...})
foobar.bar // inferred as 'bar'
```

Comment: I don't want to have to enumerate possible keys like `'foo' | 'bar'`.